# LINQ to XML extract nested elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm new to LINQ and XML parsing and rather new to C# programming. For the following XML structure, I'm trying to extract the nested elements:

```
  <persons>
    <person>
      <personNumber>2</personNumber>
      <info>free text</info>
      <addresses>
        <address>
          <city>XXX</city>
          <location>1</location>
        </address>
        <address>
          <city>YYY</city>
          <location>2</location>
        </address>
      </addresses>
    </person>
    <person>
      <personNumber>3</personNumber>
      <info>free text</info>
      <addresses>
        <address>
          <city>XXX</city>
          <location>1</location>
        </address>
        <address>
          <city>YYY</city>
          <location>2</location>
        </address>
      </addresses>
    </person>
  </persons>
```

I want to be able to fetch all the city and location for all persons with personNumber = 2!

Comment: Ok, how can we help?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Hint: find all `person` elements, filter to those with `personNumber` of 2, then use `Descendants("address")` to get address elements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way using linq:

```
var result = from p in xmlDoc.Descendants("person")
             from a in p.Descendants("address")
             where p.Element("personNumber").Value == "2" 
             select new 
                 { 
                   City = a.Element("city").Value, 
                   Location = a.Element("location").Value 
                 };
```

Comment: Simpler and probably more efficient than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sth like the following should work:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"mypath\persons.xml");

var q = from e in xmlDoc.Descendants("person")
        where e.Element("personNumber").Value == "2"
        let address = e.Descendants("address")
        from a in address
        select new {
           city = a.Element("city").Value,
           location = a.Element("location").Value
        };
```

With the sample xml provided in the OP the above linq query produces the following result:

```
[0] = { city = "XXX", location = "1" }
[1] = { city = "YYY", location = "2" }
```